# Does Visual Studio 2012 use worker process w3wp?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

When working with Visual Studio 2008 I can see worker process running in the task manager, but with  VS 2012 I cannot see the worker process running in the task manager. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio 2012 uses IIS Express by default, the process in process list is iisexpress.exe